# can we make a game with python in unity?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unity-game-engine

I have few questions about programming a game (3d or 2d) with a python language and Unity game engine
Can we make a game with python in Unity game engine?
if yes how?
please share basic tutorials about this topic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: Good Luck  Kia4king !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unity originally comes with support for scripting in C# and Javascript by default. If you wish to utilize all the features of Unity3d, I would recommend you script in either of these.

That being said, there are third party interpreters and plugins that enable you to use Python on unity, but I would recommend sticking to C#

Refer these for ways to use Python in Unity:

[UniPython - Python Scripting in Unity3D based games](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unipython-python-scripting-in-unity3d-based-games.190418/)

[Python interpreter in Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/python-interpreter-in-unity.86461/)

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is not a way to directly use python within unity. You can use an interpreter that will call functions. This can only take you so far beyond the built in functions that unity currently used.

Since you already know Python and probably learned Java in school or have at least seen it. C# is a very simple language to pick up that is very versatile so I would recommend learning it.

Otherwise you can go Piglet or Arcade Game Engine. These engines are built for Python, Piglet does not need outside libraries / dependencies. You could also go with a Blueprint style coding method, both are available with unity and unreal.